# Finding city area by city, region, country using overpass API

Tags: area, overpass-api

I am trying to define area for a particular city to find things in this area. I know about queries `area[name="New York"]; node[...](area)`. The problem with such queries is that there can be many areas for a particular name. Let's use Atlanta, Georgia, US as example. There are many areas called "Atlanta", and many "Georgia". The best query I came up with is:

```
(area["ISO3166-1"="US"][admin_level=2]; )->.country;
(area["name"="Georgia"]["border_type"="state"])->.state;
(area["name"="Atlanta"])->.city;
node[...filter for node...](area.country)(area.state)(area.city);
```

I.e. I defined 3 areas and I use their intersection, and it works. In addition I can use tags to better define region and city areas, but it seems there is no single tag/key defining well region or city, different tags are used for different cities. "border_type"="state" works only for US http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:border_type, so at this level it's hard to use keys and tags if you target all countries.

Is it the best way to uniquely identify area for City in Region, in Country?

I have feeling that my query is pretty expensive.

And why is it so hard to "resolve" city, region, country?

I am very new to overpass API, this is what 1 day of learning brought me to.

Comment: Just found a newer (2015) syntax: area["ISO3166-1"="US"][admin_level=2];
rel(area)["name"="Georgia"]["border_type"="state"];
map_to_area; But it's so slow for this particular query that it times out.